# Python - compare n-grams across multiple text files

Tags: python, n-gram

First time poster - I am a new Python user with limited programming skills.  Ultimately I am trying to identify and compare n-grams across numerous text documents found in the same directory.  My analysis is somewhat similar to plagiarism detection - I want to calculate the percentage of text documents in which a particular n-gram can be found.  For now, I am attempting a simpler version of the larger problem, trying to compare n-grams across two text documents. I have no problem identifying the n-grams but I am struggling to compare across the two documents.  Is there a way to store the n-grams in a list to effectively compare which ones are present in the two documents?  Here's what I've done so far (forgive the naive coding).  For reference, I provide basic sentences below as opposed to the text documents I am actually reading in my code.

```
import nltk
from nltk.util import ngrams

text1 = 'Hello my name is Jason'
text2 = 'My name is not Mike'

n = 3
trigrams1 = ngrams(text1.split(), n)
trigrams2 = ngrams(text2.split(), n)

print(trigrams1)
for grams in trigrams1:
    print(grams)

def compare(trigrams1, trigrams2):
    for grams1 in trigrams1:
        if each_gram in trigrams2:
            print (each_gram)
    return False
```

Thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: Any example of input files, or few rows from them?

Comment: The text documents I am reading are about 1-3 pages each.  I updated the simple example with two brief sentences for reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a list say `common` in the `compare` function. Append each ngram to this list that is common to both trigrams and finally return the list as:

```
>>> trigrams1 = ngrams(text1.lower().split(), n)  # use text1.lower() to ignore sentence case.
>>> trigrams2 = ngrams(text2.lower().split(), n)  # use text2.lower() to ignore sentence case.
>>> trigrams1
[('hello', 'my', 'name'), ('my', 'name', 'is'), ('name', 'is', 'jason')]
>>> trigrams2
[('my', 'name', 'is'), ('name', 'is', 'not'), ('is', 'not', 'mike')]
>>> def compare(trigrams1, trigrams2):
...    common=[]
...    for grams1 in trigrams1:
...       if grams1 in trigrams2:
...         common.append(grams1)
...    return common
... 
>>> compare(trigrams1, trigrams2)
[('my', 'name', 'is')]
```

Comment: `ngrams` returns a generator object, not a list. The compare function will not work unless it is converted to `list` first.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is maybe easier to concatenate the elements in the ngrams and make a list of the strings and then do the comparison.

Let's go over the process with the example you provided.

```
text1 = 'Hello my name is Jason'
text2 = 'My name is not Mike'
```

After applying the `ngrams` function from nltk you get the following two lists that I similarly name `text1` and `text2` as before:

```
text1 = [('Hello', 'my', 'name'), ('my', 'name', 'is'), ('name', 'is', 'Jason')]
text2 = [('My', 'name', 'is'), ('name', 'is', 'not'), ('is', 'not', 'Mike')]
```

When you want to compare the ngrams, you should lowercase all the elements, lest it count `'my'` and `'My'` as separate tokens, something that we obviously don't want.

The following function does exactly that.

```
def append_elements(n_gram):
    for element in range(len(n_gram)):
            phrase = ''
            for sub_element in n_gram[element]:
                    phrase += sub_element+' '
            n_gram[element] = phrase.strip().lower()
    return n_gram
```

So if we feed it `text1` we get `['hello my name', 'my name is', 'name is jason']` which is easier to process.

Next we make the `compare` function. You were right in assuming that we could use a list to store commonalities. I named it `common` here:

```
def compare(n_gram1, n_gram2):
    n_gram1 = append_elements(n_gram1)
    n_gram2 = append_elements(n_gram2)
    common = []
    for phrase in n_gram1:
        if phrase in n_gram2:
            common.append(phrase)
    if not common:
        return False
        # or you could print a message saying no commonality was found
    else:
        for i in common:
            print(i)
```

`if not common` means if the `common` list is empty, in which case it prints a message or returns `False`

Now in your example, when we run `compare(text1, text2)` the only commonality is:

```
>>> 
my name is
>>>
```

which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a task very similar to yours when I came across this old thread which seemed to work pretty well except there was one bug. I will add this answer here in case someone else stumbles upon this. The `ngrams` from `nltk.util` returns a generator object and not a list. It would need to be converted to a list to use the `compare` function that you wrote. Using `lower()` for case insensitive match.

Complete example:

```
import nltk
from nltk.util import ngrams

text1 = 'Hello my name is Jason'
text2 = 'My name is not Mike'

n = 3
trigrams1 = ngrams(text1.lower().split(), n)
trigrams2 = ngrams(text2.lower().split(), n)

def compare_ngrams(trigrams1, trigrams2):
    trigrams1 = list(trigrams1)
    trigrams2 = list(trigrams2)
    common=[]
    for gram in trigrams1:
        if gram in trigrams2:
            common.append(gram)
    return common

common = compare_ngrams(trigrams1, trigrams2)
print(common)
```

Output:

```
[('my', 'name', 'is')]
```